# Error: pip install scipy

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have python 2.6.6 installed in my oracle linux

I ran the command to install the package

```
pip install scipy
```

However I am getting the following error

```
[root@bigdatadev3 Downloads]# pip install scipy
    DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
    Collecting scipy
      Using cached scipy-0.18.1.tar.gz
    Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ... error
      Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-zu4ibh/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpDdmSFupip-wheel- --python-tag cp26:
      usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: -c --help-commands
         or: -c cmd --help

      error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for scipy
      Running setup.py clean for scipy
      Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-zu4ibh/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:

      `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

        - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
        - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                    files that aren't checked into the git repo)

      Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).


      ----------------------------------------
      Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
    Failed to build scipy
    Installing collected packages: scipy
      Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
        Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-zu4ibh/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RLPNZW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

        Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
        with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

          - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                           release)
          - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


        lapack_opt_info:
        openblas_lapack_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_mkl_info:
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib64
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_info:
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib64
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_info:
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1532: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
          warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
        lapack_info:
          libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1543: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
          warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1546: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
          NOT AVAILABLE

        Running from scipy source directory.
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-build-zu4ibh/scipy/setup.py", line 415, in <module>
        setup_package()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-zu4ibh/scipy/setup.py", line 411, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
          File "/tmp/pip-build-zu4ibh/scipy/setup.py", line 335, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1000, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 969, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
          File "scipy/setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 1000, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 969, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
          File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy-1.11.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
          File "scipy/linalg/setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
        numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-zu4ibh/scipy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-RLPNZW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zu4ibh/scipy/
```

What am I missing here?

**Issue Resolved**

I resolved the issue as follows

- ran `yum install lapack` and `yum install blas-devel lapack-devel`
- ran `pip install scipy`

It took sometime to execute `Running setup.py install for scipy ...` but finally it's installed now

Comment: Try updating pip.

Comment: It's up to date

Comment: Upgrade Python, like it suggests. Make sure `wheel` is installed with `pip install wheel` and it's up to date. What does that do?

Comment: I cannot upgrade my python, I have to use 2.6.6

Comment: wheel is already installed

Comment: The last [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) package I found is `0.16.0  np19py26_0  defaults`.  This is binary and should work.

Comment: isn't there any other way to install scipy? referring to this tar --> https://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/?source=typ_redirect

Comment: Neither the python version deprecation, or not being able to build the wheel should stop you building `scipy`. Your main problem is that the required dependencies are not present on your system. I am not familiar with this distribution, but you need either `lapack` or `atlas` - try installing these with your package manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue Resolved**

I resolved the issue as follows

- ran `yum install lapack` and `yum install blas-devel lapack-devel`
- ran `pip install scipy`

It took sometime to execute `Running setup.py install for scipy ...`

but finally it's installed now

Comment: I had to install a few more Ubuntu packages, but this seemed to work for me: `sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy libzmq-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev libatlas-dev gfortran`